# Как вставить расширенный ArrayAdapter в GridView?

Tags: android

пытаюсь добавить в данный пример http://metanit.com/java/android/5.6.php  GridView

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:layout_width="73dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:paddingLeft="16dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Название"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/capital"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Столица"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private State[] states = {

    new State ("Бразилия", "Бразилиа", R.drawable.brasil),
    new State ("Аргентина", "Буэнос-Айрес", R.drawable.argentina),
    new State ("Колумбия", "Богота", R.drawable.columbia),
    new State ("Уругвай", "Монтевидео", R.drawable.uruguay),
    new State ("Чили", "Сантьяго", R.drawable.chilie),
    new State ("Бразилия", "Бразилиа", R.drawable.brasil),
    new State ("Аргентина", "Буэнос-Айрес", R.drawable.argentina),
    new State ("Колумбия", "Богота", R.drawable.columbia),
    new State ("Уругвай", "Монтевидео", R.drawable.uruguay),
    new State ("Чили", "Сантьяго", R.drawable.chilie),
    new State ("Бразилия", "Бразилиа", R.drawable.brasil),
    new State ("Аргентина", "Буэнос-Айрес", R.drawable.argentina),
    new State ("Колумбия", "Богота", R.drawable.columbia),
    new State ("Уругвай", "Монтевидео", R.drawable.uruguay),
    new State ("Чили", "Сантьяго", R.drawable.chilie),
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    setListAdapter(new StateAdapter(states));
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            // получаем выбранный пункт
            State selectedState = (State)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Был выбран пункт " + selectedState.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
}
private State getModel(int position) {
    return(((StateAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position));
}
class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    StateAdapter(State[] list) {
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.activity_main,  list);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View row=convertView;
         if(row==null){

            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
             holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.flag);
             holder.nameView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
             holder.capitalView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.capital);
             row.setTag(holder);
         }
        else{

             holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
         }

        State state = getModel(position);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource((state.getFlagResource()));
        holder.nameView.setText(state.getName());
        holder.capitalView.setText(state.getCapital());

        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView nameView, capitalView;
    }
}
}
```

при запуске на эмуляторе получаю ошибку:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.langUnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

ругается на эту строку:

```
row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
```

поясните, как переделать исходный пример под GridView ?

Answer (score 1):

замените `R.layout.activity_main` (это слой только для экрана активности) на слой, который отрисовывает элемент списка. Например, он может иметь такое название

```
R.layout.item_for_list
```